# Comparison and estimation of new curve data via using reference curve mean and std values?

Tags: matlab, probability, mean, standard-deviation, probability-density

Here I want to compare the power curve of two different turbine.Let us assume you have two tables tb1 for turbine 1(Have X=speed AND X1=power  values) and tb2 for turbine 2(have y=speed and y1=power values) .Now in with the help of tb1 datas; I calculated binEdge(using X) and then did binning (using x1) so that with the help of std and mean values we know the distribution ,as you can see the code below:

```
binEdges = linspace(min(X),max(X),numBins); 
[N,binEdges] = histcounts(X, binEdges);

for i = 1:numBins
flagBinMembers = (binEdges == i); 
binMembers    = X1(flagBinMembers);
BinMean(i)    = mean(binMembers); 
BinStd(i)     = std(binMembers);
end
```

Now in tb2, I want to check the values of speed or y distribution w.r.t above calculated std and mean values. Once I know the location or in which distribution y or speed belongs then I want to estimates its corresponding power value by doing some probability test.This power further can be verified with available power y1 to see weather estimated power values is correct or not.

Comment: What do you mean by "probability test", specifically?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth  chi square test with probability distribution function

Comment: Did you try searching for "Matlab chi squared test"?

Comment: I know matlab chi squared test but I don't know how I can related my mu and sigma of reference data (Which I have calculated) to my incoming data.... There is no such matlab function

Comment: Your `flagBinMembers` seems incorrect, did you mean: `binMembers    = X(X>binEdges(k) & X<binEdges(k+1))`?

Comment: As I said below, _It seems like you give to much attention to the binning while this is just an arbitrary way to divide the data_, you should use some model fitting like regression for this problem

Answer (score 1):

If you have Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox, and all you want is estimating the parameters of `binMembers` and then see if `X1` comes from the same distribution:

```
numBins = 5;
binEdges = linspace(min(X),max(X),numBins);
N = histcounts(X, binEdges);

for k = 1:numBins-1
    binMembers = X(X>=binEdges(k) & X<binEdges(k+1));
    if ~isempty(binMembers)
        is_X1_fit = ~chi2gof(X1,'CDF',makedist('Normal',...
            'mu',mean(binMembers),'sigma',std(binMembers)))
    else
            disp('bin is empty')
    end
end
```

`is_X1_fit` will return 1 if `X1` belongs to the `binMembers` distribution, and 0 otherwise.

Comment: 'CDF' is an argument of the `chi2gof` function, and it's used to compare the  distributions, just as good as you can do it with PDF, but PDF is not an  argument of `chi2gof`. In any way, this is just to make a "probability distribution object" to pass to `chi2gof`.

Comment: Is this another question? your "data" is X or some other data? What you want to compare to X1?

Comment: My apology if you could not able to understand the problem. Hence I have written the sample of code with more description my problem statement.

Comment: @Sujal I'm sorry you got me lost. Now I don't understand your question at all. It seems like you give to much attention to the binning while this is just an arbitrary way to divide the data. It is not clear what do you want to infer from this tests? what is the relation between X and X1 or Y and Y1? Maybe you should try to explain your real goal instead of using X and Y in such a vague way.

Comment: I would like to thank you from my bottom of heart that your are the first person I have seen here who asking me patiently without getting rude. Now come to your point. I have given all details like X or X1 in my updated question. Please have a look and tell me weather you understand it or not :)

Comment: Why you don't use regression? You sould fit a model to `X1` as a function of `X`, then estimate it for the data in `Y` and see how close you get to `Y1`.